# Assigning Pairs to Already Defined Vars in Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin, var

I'm trying to return a pair from a function and assign it to already defined variables, in **Kotlin**.

The way I've seen pairs received from a function until now is:

```
val/var (thing1, thing2) = FunctionReturningPair()
```

Is it possible to assign already defined variables to the pair? Something like:

```
var thing1: String
var thing2:int
//do other things here
(thing1, thing2) = FunctionReturningPair() 
//note that thing1 and thing2 were ALREADY DEFINED.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a reason of why that would not work, but apparently it does not. In the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html#destructuring-in-lambdas), I don't see any mention of doing that as well. Usually features are added if there is a consensus that 1. people consider that they are needed. And 2. they are not going to break other things / or be confusing. So I guess that one of those conditions has not been met, or nobody ask for it.

If you really want it, it might be worth checking [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues) to see if somebody else requested it. If they have vote for it, and if not, write a feature request.

Until then, I guess that you are stuck with one of these ways:

```
val p = functionReturningPair()
thing1 = p.first
thing2 = p.second
```

OR

```
functionReturningPair().let { (first, second) -> thing1 = first; thing2 = second }
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately that's not allowed as far as I know. The current Kotlin syntax allows for [destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html), but that only works if you **declare** the variables at that time. In your example you declared the variables above and just want to assign a value.

Looking at the [grammar](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html) makes it clear that [`assignment`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#assignment) only accepts a `directlyAssignableExpression` (such as a [`simpleIdentifier`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#simpleIdentifier)). A [`declaration`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#declaration) instead accepts a [`multiVariableDeclaration`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#multiVariableDeclaration).